# Why am I having so many problems with WordPress when I followed the guide exactly as outlined?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, wordpress

I got a WordPress VPS through [This hosting provider](http://www.vps.net/) and I spent several months trying to figure out why WordPress is unable to communicate with the web server and stuff directly.

The only thing I've been able to do is set permissions to 7777, with the ownership `wordpressuser:www-data`.

In this guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04) one of the things it wants me to do is

```
curl -O https://download.wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

When I went to

```
cd /tmp
```

and performed a

```
tar xzvf latest.tar.gz
```

using

```
wordpressuser:~$ sudo
```

it gave me this error.

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I was able to get past this by downloading a zipped version which I extracted to `/var/www/html/blog`

Next, it wanted me to change file and directory  ownership permissions.
Here's where things get strange. When I type

```
sudo chmod g+w /var/www/html/blog/wp-content
```

and then I use the `-R` flag for the next two directories inside `wp-content`,

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/themes
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins
```

When I went to check it out using Win SCP, everything was either 1777 or 7777. The 0660 permissions of the `.htaccess` file made it show a 403 forbidden message.

```
You do not have permission to access this page could not read .htaccess file
```

, and it's set to `wordpressuser:www-data` and I added this user to the group `www-data`

The other problem is that even when I have everything set to `wordpressuser:www-data` with 7777 permissions, WordPress cannot, for some odd reason, remove the old plugins, saying

```
the plugin update has failed, update successful, closing maintenance mode.
```

I really, really want to find a quick for this because this has been going on for a long long time. >:(

Comment: I am totally blind. I do not know how to format. I use the &lt; and &gt; because I am familiar with HTML commands, graphical formatting interfaces are not accessible with screen readers.

Comment: @user24489 the formatting here is done using a simple format specification called Markdown, which uses backticks, spaces, asterisks etc. to provide a limited subset of HTML formatting options. See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help (not sure how accessible that page is, but the method for creating code blocks is written out clearly). Overall, Markdown should be easier for you to use than plain HTML.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch thank you for assisting user24489 with editing and formatting.

Comment: I read the editing-help but still find it confusing to read with a screen reader. I noticed that when I pressed down arrow, the code or command lines are on a separate line. Is there a stack-exchange site where I can ask about accessible formatting options when it comes to codes?

Comment: You can ask about the formatting used here on [meta] or https://meta.stackexchange.com. Essentially, the formatting for code is this: if it's meant to be a block of code, start with an empty line, then indent each line of code or output with 4 spaces. If the code is meant to be part of a bigger sentence, use backticks around it (an example of this would be the second paragraph in this question).

Comment: Thanks, that made more sense. I saw that you hit enter twice, hit space bar four times, wrote the code, and then hit enter two times again. Sometimes I noticed one space after the second carriage return. What is a backpick? I didn't see that anywhere when I opened up the editing page.

Answer (score 0):

As I read through your question, I think your problem is with file permissions and some weird way of setting up your VPS.

Your VPS is running fine right? If not, then read this [article](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website/) for setting up your VPS. The video makes more sense than reading it cause it generalize things with certain scenario. This [article](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04/) might help as well when it come to Installing WordPress

Can you show your error.log content? That can give the precise error.

**Now to solve your Problem.**

Always keep in mind NEVER to give a `chmod 777` permission to you files.

That's gonna be a fatal lesson of security for you.

Wordpress needs a proper `read - write` permission to work. To make sure everythings fine, try this:

Go to you `public_html` folder and run the commands

```
chown www-data:www-data  -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After that, you might wanna tighten your security, read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

If you want to make changes, just do what you did above, then tighten your security once more.

Hope this helps!

-Dave

Comment: Thanks, but I have applied these fixes. When I did a 755 on all my riectories and 644 on all of my files under the name www-data:www-data, WordPress said it could not write into the directory to make updates. Similarly, It was not able to delete old plug-ins, even when permission was set to 777, and ownership was set to www-data. I am thinking of going from vps dot net to linode dot com and see if I can try these things on a Debian 8 server.

Comment: Any progress today?

Comment: No progress. Everything is still the same. the latest.tar.gz will not extract as the guide wants me to. No matter how hard I try, the chmod g+w will not work. It doesn't affect the file permissions one bit. I'm just going to close my Linux box on that provider and get a Linode one, and hoope I have some success with that.